# Tool for downloading map data from Public websites which has Google as Base map

Tags: google-maps, web-service, download

I am trying to download the map data (coverage map) from the [MAXIS web site](https://maxisnetwork.tuxgeo.com/v2/). I couldn't find any option to download it directly. This web service has coverage map of two different band widths with Google as base map.

Can we take this URL https://maxisnetwork.tuxgeo.com/v2/) and put it in some applications and download the coverage map data?

[image: MAXIS network coverage map]

I have done some research but couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> ... and download the coverage map data?

I suppose it depends what you mean by downloading the data, if you mean get at the vector data from which the maps are made then the answer is **no**.

If on the other hand you mean get at the data as images (the 3G and 4G data are served as individual layers in a GeoWebCache service), then the technical answer is ***yes***.

For example, here's a URL to get at a tile from the 3G coverage layer:

https://maxisnetwork.tuxgeo.com/geoserver/gwc/service/gmaps?SRS=EPSG:900913&layers=maxis:coverage-3g&zoom=9&x=402&y=251&format=image/png8

and here's a URL to get at a tile from the 4G coverage layer:

https://maxisnetwork.tuxgeo.com/geoserver/gwc/service/gmaps?SRS=EPSG:900913&layers=maxis:coverage-4g&zoom=9&x=402&y=251&format=image/png8

For more information on GeoWebCache see the [documentation](http://geowebcache.org/docs/current/)

There is also an associated WMS with service end point of:

`http://maxisnetwork.tuxgeo.com/geoserver/maxis/wms?`

You can use this WMS service end point to view the service in QGIS

[image: MAXIS WMS in QGIS]

Comment: Thank you very much @nmtoken. Can we use this WMS layer and capture the polygons in QGIS / Mapinfo / any other GIS application or can we create any other openlayer application to capture this? Please suggest.

Comment: You can use OpenLayers, or QGIS or MapInfo to view the data (as images) from the services, but there is no direct way to capture the actual polygon data.

Comment: I tried connecting WMS to Mapinfo/ QGIS. But I am unable to see the data in map window both in QGIS and MapInfo. I am getting this error HTTP 400. Unable to retrieve the map image from WMS Server. How to achieve this ?

Comment: what URL did you use?

Comment: here is the [URL](http://maxisnetwork.tuxgeo.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?).  once I added this to MIPro / QGIS I am able to choose which layer I want to select as WMS, then I tried with all 3 formats and all 3 available layers I didn't had luck to get them. In QGIS I am able to get the WMS layers into Table of contents but not able to see any content in the map window and in MapInfo i am getting HTTP Error 400. please suggest the necessary steps to achieve this.

Comment: The WMS endpoint has changed. I was able to use the end point `http://maxisnetwork.tuxgeo.com/geoserver/maxis/wms?` to view the service

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55056/discussion-between-bunny-chowdary-and-nmtoken).

Comment: whatever you have got in your QGIS application. That's exactly what I want, How Can I back to that?